# BSOD 0x8E STATUS_SINGLE_STEP

Tags: c#, .net, driver, bsod, kaspersky

I have a BSOD 0x8E every day on five devices in same times on Windows 7.

Allways exception code - 04 - STATUS_SINGLE_STEP 
as example:

```
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000008e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: 80000004, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: ffdff2a5, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: a9c34d48, Trap Frame
Arg4: 00000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.17514.x86fre.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1002

BIOS_DATE:  06/04/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  P8H61-I LX R2.0

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffff80000004

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffffffffdff2a5

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffffffa9c34d48

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000004 (2147483652) - <Unable to get error code text>

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
ffdff2a5 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al

TRAP_FRAME:  a9c34d48 -- (.trap 0xffffffffa9c34d48)
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=846410c0 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0c4cdb04 edi=00000000
eip=ffdff2a5 esp=a9c34dbc ebp=801ef000 iopl=0         ov dn di ng nz na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00004c86
ffdff2a5 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al          ds:0023:00000000=??
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 2

CPU_MHZ: a8c

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3a,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 17'00000000 (cache) 17'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK_0x8E

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x8E

PROCESS_NAME:  avp.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  NETMANNOTE

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  11-17-2017 12:11:18.0584

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 x86fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to ffdff2a5

STACK_TEXT:  
a9c34db8 00000000 0000027f 00000000 00000000 0xffdff2a5


STACK_COMMAND:  .trap 0xffffffffa9c34d48 ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK_0x8E

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BAD_STACK

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BAD_STACK_0x8E

TARGET_TIME:  2017-11-16T13:53:07.000Z

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  1000

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  336

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer EmbeddedNT SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2010-11-20 11:42:49

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  101119-1850

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_rtm

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.17514.x86fre.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  cc3

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:bad_stack_0x8e

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {993602b9-6aa7-fbab-86a8-bb6ad81a3997}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

The service name can be different: av.exe, scvhost.ext,..
I know that is due to the a driver does not process STATUS_SINGLE_STEP exception.
Is any idea how to find wrong driver? There is no stack and module name in the dump...

I tried to run the Mirosoft Driver Verifier with standart flags and all drivers without Microsoft drivers, dump listing is above.